# How can I notify ReSharper that the return value of a local function is NotNull / CanBeNull?

Tags: c#, resharper, local-functions

Is there any way to notify ReSharper that the return value of a local function is `NotNull` or `CanBeNull`?

Otherwise I need to convert local functions into member functions or turn off the pessimistic nullability checking because they produces tons of warnings.

---

**EDIT**

I know that attributes are not supported in local functions, but I wondered that there are any tricks instead.

For example, you can't put an attribute inside a method, but you can disable warning once with comment by writing `// ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming`. I'm looking for a trick like this.

Comment: MIght be relevant: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/794

Comment: Thank you, @SzabolcsDézsi! I know that attributes are not supported in local functions, but I wondered that there is any workaround instead. Please refer to the edited question.